# how to do page switching and active bottom navigation at the same time?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, block, bloc

```
@overrideWidget build(BuildContext context) {
final PageController controller = PageController();
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: PageView(
      controller: controller,
      children: const [
        Center(
          child: Text("Page 0"),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text("Page 1"),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BlocListener<MenuBloc, MenuState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      controller.jumpToPage(state.index);
    },
    child: BlocBuilder<MenuBloc, MenuState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.explore),
              label: state.index.toString(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.apps),
              label: state.index.toString(),
            ),
          ],
          onTap: (index) =>
              context.read<MenuBloc>().add(MenuSwitch(state.index)),
          selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

i want both? how to make it work properly when the selected item is active and changing pages?

> Blockquote
> how to do page switching and active bottom navigation at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It's Worked, With A Little Observation I finally realized it returns index doesn't need state anymore :)